# how to install MySQL in macos Ventura?

Tags: mysql, macos

Is there a way to do this without using a virtual box.

MySQL only supports macos 12- this means macos Ventura is not supported.

Comment: Describe what you tried to install it and exactly what happened?

Comment: Do you need MySQL? MariaDB is running on Ventura. You may install it with brew

Comment: thanks, but I need MySQL

Comment: nothing that much to try!

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Had to go to Ventura for Xcode.  Can't find any statements if Oracle/MySQL are even working on this, when it might be available. Looks like I'll be updating my database directly in prod on the cloud server. Not good. Lost all my snippets from Workbench

Answer (score 0):

I am running Server version: 8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL
on Ventura 13.2.1 -- it works for me.

I had it installed on Big Sur, and used Migration Assistant to set up the Ventura Machine, and everything was installed, databases copied, etc.

-- more information.. The migrated version worked, but it was an x86 binary, and my new machine was Apple Silicon.  So I went through the process of uninstalling homebrew, reinstalling homebrew, and installing all my homebrew software.  Tedious, but now I am running 8.0.26 MySQL as an "arm" binary. Never had to reload the database.